# HERE API - Paris speed limits

Tags: here-api

I would like to know if the HERE API results apply the recent speed limit in Paris (https://www.msn.com/en-us/news/world/paris-limits-car-speed-to-30-kmhour-in-bid-to-boost-safety-air-quality/ar-AANUgux).

Comment: Yes. Usually, such updates happen very fast at HERE with weekly updates. Do you have specific coordinates where it does not apply?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Hello, our map content team is looking into it. We'll get back to you on this

Comment: On september the 8th, you answered me by Tweeter "Hi, the updates should be available in the next up to two weeks. Hope that's helpful. "

Answer (score 0):

We have a response from the Map content team that, Paris: the speed limit of 30km/h has been implemented on the majority of Municipality attributes in the latest map release.

Useful speed limit demo
Link : https://tcs.ext.here.com/examples/v3/rme_speed_limits